# Shall Tomcat SSL cert match with the same CA as client cert in mutual authentication?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have received a bunch of files (keystores, pfx, jks etc.). I'm going to prepare mutual authentication on Tomcat 9, JDK 8. I was able to setup secure connection between tomcat and browser so the keystore and password are correct. I'm trying to authenticate client via cert. I have got some certiticate (jks) but I can see this cert was signed by different CA than tomcat cert contained in keystore. Since I plan to setup truststore and provide CA for client inside this store shall all the certificates be signesd by the same CA?

Because there is separate param for truststore I think there is no need to have all the certs signed by the same CA. I've got stuck because I receive 403 every time I try to connect to server. There are only some strange logs that may cause the issue, but I'm not sure:

```
RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: warning. close_notify
client change_cipher_spec[-1]
server change_cipher_spec[-1]
```

There are no exceptions or errors regarding imrpoper connection or missing cert. Any idea?

Comment: The client and server certs can be of different CA.

Comment: The client trusts the server CA
The server trusts the client CA
In java world, we add this at two places, truststore and java installation\lib\security\cacerts 
When you say you have setup secure connection between tomcat and browser does it mean you have tested mutual authenitaction from the browser where you had to present a client certificate